# Android - keeping a single element contained on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gui

I'm experimenting to see if the layout scheme I want to use is possible. I want to have an `XML` layout that's **scrollable**. Within that scrollable layout, I want to have a single line going horizontally across the screen (I used just a View with a fixed height and different color). When that horizontal line reaches the top of the screen, and as I scroll down through the layout, I want it to stop and remain at the top of the screen while being able to scroll through everything below it.

I've been messing around in XML trying to get it to work, basically putting a bunch of junk before it and after it.

Any ideas as to how that might work? Would I have to do something fancy with the java code to fix the red line at the top when the scroll position reaches a certain point? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean vertical line instead of horizontal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want something like Gmail app where when you scroll a mail the header sticks on top... To do this, you need 2 views. You have your regular scroller below and overlay a fixed view on top (you can use a relative layout to do this). When your cell goes past a certain spot, you want to populate and set the visibility of the fixed view to VISIBLE. This would give the impression that the view you want to 'stick' to the top really just got stuck rather than scrolled out of view. You'll have to work out the opposite scrolling scenario too based on the location and height of the scrolled cell/view.

HTH

Comment: One thing that might make it a little more complicated is that the horizontal line is eventually going to be a row of buttons (press a button and change the scrolling layout below it). It seems like overlaying a relative layout and messing with visibility might break the ability to press the buttons.