# How can I implement a ListView within a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a simple Checkbook app, whose MainActivity stores a list of transactions. I would like a TextView at the top and bottom of the screen that show the account balance and an option to add a new transaction, respectively. I would like a list of transactions in between that scroll. I was able to implement a ListView and add a header and footer view, but if the transaction list exceeds the size of the screen the headers and footers can scroll off screen.

Is there any way to position a ListView within the linear layout, or freeze the headers/footers to stay on the screen?

Here is my XML file so far:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/default_header_string">
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/transaction_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/add_transaction_string">
</TextView>
```

And here is my onCreate, which has no syntax errors but I am unable to click the footerview to add a transaction:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbook);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.transaction_list_view);

    // Create a new Adapter
    mAdapter = new TransactionAdapter(list.getContext());

    // Inflate footerView and headerView
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    TextView headerView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, null);
    TextView footerView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);

    // Set listener for footerView
    footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent transactionIntent = new Intent(CheckbookActivity.this, AddTransactionActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(transactionIntent, ADD_TRANSACTION_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you say me why you depend on the LinearLayout. W ether it'll be done easily with RelativeLayout.

Comment: Well, I tried using just a ListView, because you can add footer and header views, but as my list grows longer these views scroll off the screen, and I tried to find a way to keep them on screen. I want the user to ALWAYS see the account balance, and ALWAYS see the option to add a new transaction.

Comment: Yes my friend it will possible  with the RelativeLayout easily then LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the below code. This will satisfy your requirement. I tried this and working for me.
Relative layout with below,above attributes. Relativelayout is better than Linear layout with weight method.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="ListView Heading" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="ListView Footer" />

<ListView 
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
     android:layout_above="@id/textView2"

    ></ListView>
```

The UI will like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that set up the exact layout I wanted!

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote yet. I'll be sure to come around and do so when I do.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. There ya go! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with weightsum and `layout_weight` in linearlayout and also you can create this type of view using RelativeLayout.

1) In LinearLayout just add `weightsum="1"` to your linearlayout and add `layout_weight="0.2"` to each of your header and footer and add `layout_weight="0.6"` to your listview.

2) In relativeLayout add alignParentTop to your header and alignParentBottom to your footer and set listview to `layout_below="@+id/header"` and `layout_above="2+id/footer"`

Comment: The layout weight was a good idea. I think in this particular case the layout_above and layout_below method worked best, because it allows me to play around with text sizes and such without concerning myself about screwing up the size of other objects. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, hope this will help you to solve your problem.
Instead of using header/footer just put as below code in your XML:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/default_header_string">
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/transaction_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_transaction_string">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That was a good idea, I implemented something really similar based on your answer as well as the relative layout that the other person shared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12947697/3202658) for your problem from a similiar post. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That is similar to what I was trying to do, and it's definitely an idea for a layout I can implement in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to accomplish to freeze the header/footer. It will be easier to use a relative layout to position the header/footer then have your listview in the middle

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/default_header_string">
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/transaction_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_view"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_view">
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/add_transaction_string">
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use a LinearLayout for this task. But I don't recommend it as it's a bit "hacky".

Comment: Thanks! You were right, the RelativeLayout works a lot better for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all the elements in a array: Example:- (weatherArray)
2. Loop through all the elements :-

Example:-

```
mainLayout = ((LinearLayout)refreshObj.get("mainLayout"));
    mainLayout.removeAllViews();

for (int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {

 View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.weather_row4_item,   mainLayout,false); 

 TextView todayTempStatus = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.todayTempStatus);

todayTempStatus.setText("");

}
```

1. This is an example without using listview, which we will populate lienarlayout using child view.